# How do I access previous promise response in a .then() chain in axios?

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, axios

I need access to responseA to get access to a field value further along the chained request. How can that be done elegantly?

```
  axios.get(`/endpoint`) 
            .then((responseA) => {
               // Do something with responseA
               return axios.put(signedUrl, file, options); 
            })
            .then((responseB) => {
               // Do something with responseA & responseB
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err.message);
            });
```

UPDATE: I should probably mention that in my first .then() I return another network request. And it has to happen in sequence.

Comment: What **exactly** are those _"Do something"_ parts? Does `responseB` come from some action determined by `responseA` or are they independent?

Comment: Define a variable outside the promise chain and assign the responseA to me or use async/await which is more imperative style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Promise.all`:

```
axios.get(`/endpoint`) 
.then(
  responseA =>
    Promise.all([
      responseA,
      axios.get("/endpointB")
    ])   
)
.then(
  ([responseA,responseB]) => {
  console.log(responseA,responseB);
})
.catch((err) => {
    console.log(err.message);
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You have a number of options to do this.

1) Break the chain

```
let promiseA = axios.get(`/endpoint`) 
let promiseB = promiseA.then((responseA) => {
               // Do something with responseA
            })

return Promise.all([promiseA, promiseB]).then(function([responseA, responseB]) {
        // Do what you must
});
```

2) Use await

```
let responseA = await axios.get('/endpoint/')
// You can figure out the rest
```

Answer (score 5):

What is happening inside the first `.then()` block? In theory, you could return the values you need from responseA to the second `.then()` block, as whatever you return from the first `then` block will be available as responseB. In other words, it would look something like this:

```
axios.get(`/endpoint`) 
        .then((responseA) => {
           // additional request/logic
           const moreData = someFunction()
           return { responseAdata: responseA.dataYouWant, moreData: moreData }
        })
        .then((responseB) => {
           // now responseA values will be available here as well, e.g.
           responseB.responseAdata
           // Do something with responseA & responseB
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err.message);
        });
```

Comment: you could simplify that with [deconstructing array arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still facing problem then try as below :

```
  axios.get('https://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/direct?q=' + req.body.city + '&limit=1&appid=e43ace140d2d7bd6108f3458e8f5c')
        .then(
            (response1) => {
                let output = response1.data;
                axios.get('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' + output[0].lat + '&lon=' + output[0].lon + '&appid=e43ace1d1640d2d7bd61058e8f5c')
                    .then((weatherdd) => {
                        res.render('index.twig', { weatherdata: weatherdd.data, cityname: req.body.city, todaydatex: todayDate });
                    })
            }
        )
        .catch(
            err => {
                res.send(err)
            }
        );
```

Hint: As You can see I am using response1 which is returned from the first request and then defined a local variable with output and finally using the data in my next HTTP request (eg: output[0].lat)